Help troubleshoot multiple Bands on gel (Conventional PCR)
I designed sequencing primers (Sanger) for MPL gene. The length of the product is 543 bp. Checked the parameters of primers with Multiple primer analyzer (Thermo), NCBI- Primer Blast, Oligo evaluator (Sigma). Checked for specificity of primers with software ( Ncbi- primer blast, Genome tester, UCSC genome browser Insilico PCR). All the parameters were within the range specified. No self complementarity or hairpins/dimers.
On amplifying it and running a gel, multiple bands were seen on the gel (@1200bp, 300 bp, 400bp). There was no band corresponding to the 543bp size. ran a gradient PCR. used PCR additives. I still see multiple bands. any advice on trouble shooting ?
Protocols
DNA template
Extracted use spin-column method.
primer design
Primers designed for MPL gene on chromosome 1.
PCR protocol

26ul of platinum master mix (hot start polymerase)
2+2ul of primer (forward and reverse)
5ul of DNA extracted from peripheral blood
15ul of nuclease free water
Cycling
Initial denaturation 94 for 10 min
32 cycles of:
denaturation - 94 for 1 min
annealing - 50/52/54/56/58/60 for 1 min (GRADIENT PCR)
Extension - 72 for 1 min
final denaturation - 72 for 10 min hold -4 degrees

I didn't add mgcl2 separately. it was one of the ingredients in the master mix.
When i used DMSO, it was 1.5ul.

what is your template? see also here. Can you show complete PCR protocol including e.g. [MgCl2]?

DNA template. Extracted use spin-column method. Primers designed for MPL gene on chromosome 1.
PCR protocol
26ul of platinum master mix(hot start polymerase)
2+2ul of primer (forward and reverse)
5ul of DNA extracted from peripheral blood
15ul of nuclease free water
Initial denaturation 94 for 10 min
32 cycles of
denaturation - 94 for 1 min
annealing - 50/52/54/56/58/60 for 1 min (GRADIENT PCR)
Extension - 72 for 1 min
final denaturation - 72 for 10 min
hold -4 degrees
I didn't add mgcl2 separately. it was one of the ingredients in the master mix. When i used DMSO, it was 1.5ul

thanks- added to your question. It would help potentially to have a positive control primer set (that you know to work) to confirm that the primers are the issue rather than the DNA or the master mix.

Will do . Thank you

It could be loads of things. When I've worked on these issues (bioinformatics) it's always been complex primer design frameworks, specifically using data engineering practices for metagenomic primer design (proprietary contract - can't talk about it). However, it's a multi-pronged process. Here's the basics that should help you. The wet-lab talked through the other issues, i.e. where there was more to molecular biology than bioinformatics, here's a summary of the things usually done.
Primer Design
Even though tools gave the green light, sometimes subtle issues slip through. This stuff isn't really for this site in any case BUT ....

Specificity Check:
Reassess primer specificity using updated databases like NCBI Primer-BLAST. Small genome updates can reveal unintended matches.
Annealing Sites:
Map your primers against the MPL gene region using a UCSC Genome Browser or Insilico PCR tool to ensure no off-target regions align.

Template DNA Quality
The template can be a sneaky culprit!

DNA Integrity:
Run your extracted DNA on a gel to check for degradation or contamination. Smearing indicates degraded DNA, which affects amplification.
Contaminants:
Residual proteins, salts, or phenol from DNA prep can inhibit PCR. Purify your DNA again with a column-based cleanup kit or ethanol precipitation.

PCR Conditions
Optimization might save the day.

Annealing Temperature:
Gradient PCR was a great step! If still no luck, lower the annealing temperature slightly below the primer Tm. This may reduce nonspecific binding.
Extension Time:
Unexpected bands could result from overly long extension times, causing nonspecific fragments. For 543 bp, 30 seconds at 72°C should suffice.
Additives:
PCR enhancers like DMSO (2–5%), betaine, or BSA can sometimes reduce off-target products. You mentioned trying additives—ensure you tested them individually.

Reaction Mix Checks
The mix can make or break PCR success.

MgCl₂ Concentration:
Too much magnesium increases nonspecific amplification. Start with 1.5 mM and adjust incrementally.
Primer Concentration:
Use equimolar primers at 0.2–0.5 µM. Too much primer can promote off-target amplification.

Technical Enhancements
When the basics fail, advanced tweaks might help.

Nested PCR:
Use a second set of internal primers to amplify a specific region within the initial product.
Touchdown PCR:
Gradually reduce the annealing temperature over the first 10–15 cycles to enhance specificity.


Band-Specific Checks
Your bands don’t include the expected 543 bp product.

Gel Issues:
Confirm your DNA ladder is correct, and ensure your gel resolves the range you’re amplifying. Misinterpretation of band sizes is more common than you'd think.
Unexpected Bands:

@1200 bp: Check for template contamination or nonspecific binding far from the target site.
@300 bp and 400 bp: These might be nonspecific primer-dimers or truncated products. Reducing primer concentration and adding DMSO could help.



Sequencing Validation
If none of these branches bear fruit, try sequencing the most prominent band to identify what is amplifying. This will give insight into the template or off-target regions involved.
For troubleshooting PCR issues like yours, the following resources provide insights and guidance:
Primer Design and PCR Optimization: Sigma-Aldrich details best practices for primer design and optimization, useful for minimizing off-target effects and enhancing PCR specificity.

thank you so much for taking out time to explain.

Primer Design- check specificity with both NCBI primer blast and UCSC genome browser. Very specific. I also tried genome tester for specificity.
Extension time was kept at 72 for 30 sec and 72 for 1 min. PCR additives (DMSO alone, BSA alone, DMSO+BSA) were used.
3.Wil adjust mgcl2 concentration and check
Will try touch down PCR and see the results
5.DNA was purified to remove the contamination variable
Planning to give the amplicon for sequence and see the results
Thanks again


Thanks @Bhavani "accepts" for a post are always more welcome than a note of thanks.

If you’re consistently observing multiple bands and no product at the expected size, it suggests that your PCR reaction may not be specific enough, or other factors could be interfering with amplification. I would suggest to begin troubleshooting with 1. Template quality; 2. re-design primers and check if the primer preparation or resuspension is in good condition; 3. perform gradient PCT and optimize conditions of PCR; 4. Adjust MgCl2 concentration; 5. Prefer to use hot-start Polymerase; 6. try two step PCR; 7. gel extract the faint band and use it for further amplification; 8. redesign primers with alternate sites

why was this answer downvoted? these are all reasonable suggestions.

@MaximilianPress User posted several answers in quick succession which were AI generated. This of two that are still up. (AI is getting better, even the medical answers, which used to be very easy to detect, are much more reasonable. )

I see, thank you.

Thank you. I used Hot start polymerase. I am planning to redesign primers.
